# Does the python library "urwid" contain a widget for reading in dates (datepicker)?

Tags: python, datepicker, widget, urwid, tui

[npyscreen](https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/introduction.html) has the widgets ["DateCombo" and "TitleDateCombo"](https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/widgets-general.html#widgets-dates-sliders-and-combination-widgets) for picking dates.

**Is there anything similar in urwid?**
If not, are there any recommended third-party libraries?

Here is an example which uses npyscreen:

[image]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import npyscreen

class DateForm(npyscreen.Form):
    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def create(self):
        self.date = self.add(npyscreen.TitleDateCombo, name="Date")

class TestApplication(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        new_user = self.addForm("MAIN", DateForm, name="Read Date")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApplication().run()
```

Comment: As far as I know, `urwid` doesn't have a date picker. There are tons of urwid addon libraries (you can find many of them by [searching PyPI for 'urwid'](https://pypi.org/search/?q=urwid)), most of which are a grab-bag of a bunch of unrelated things, so you probably have to read each project's description or homepage to see if any of them have what you want. If not, you'd have to write one yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the python library [`urwid`](http://urwid.org/index.html) does not include a date picker (state of 2018). Therefore I wrote a (rudimentary) one.

The class is called [`additional_urwid_widgets.DatePicker`](https://github.com/AFoeee/additional_urwid_widgets/wiki/DatePicker) and **can be installed via [pip](https://pypi.org/project/additional-urwid-widgets/)**.

[image: Demonstration of date picker #1]
[image: Demonstration of date picker #2]

For a **stand alone example**, which illustrates the functionality of the widget, see [here](https://github.com/AFoeee/additional_urwid_widgets/blob/master/stand_alone_examples/date_picker_example.py).

For more (and simpler) **examples**, see [here](https://github.com/AFoeee/additional_urwid_widgets/wiki/DatePicker#examples).

For a more **detailed explanation** of the parameters and options, see [the corresponding github wiki entry](https://github.com/AFoeee/additional_urwid_widgets/wiki/DatePicker).

---

### Some Examples

#### Minimal

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from additional_urwid_widgets import DatePicker, MODIFIER_KEY      # installed via pip
import urwid                                                       # installed via pip

# Color schemes that specify the appearance off focus and on focus.
PALETTE = [("reveal_focus", "black", "white")]

dp = DatePicker(highlight_prop=("reveal_focus", None))        # By default, the focused picker is not highlighted!

pile = urwid.Pile([urwid.Text("press additionally the key modifier (default is 'ctrl')."),
                   urwid.Divider(" "),
                   dp])

loop = urwid.MainLoop(urwid.Filler(pile, "top"),
                      PALETTE)
loop.run()
```

[image: Demonstration of example 'Minimal']

#### Not Today

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
from additional_urwid_widgets import DatePicker, MODIFIER_KEY      # installed via pip
import urwid                                                       # installed via pip

# Color schemes that specify the appearance off focus and on focus.
PALETTE = [("reveal_focus", "black", "white")]

not_today = datetime.date(2018, 2, 20)

dp = DatePicker(initial_date=not_today,
                highlight_prop=("reveal_focus", None))        # By default, the focused picker is not highlighted!

pile = urwid.Pile([urwid.Text("press additionally the key modifier (default is 'ctrl')."),
                   urwid.Divider(" "),
                   dp])

loop = urwid.MainLoop(urwid.Filler(pile, "top"),
                      PALETTE)
loop.run()
```

[image: Demonstration of example 'Not today']

#### ISO-8601 + Styled + Compact

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import calendar
from additional_urwid_widgets import DatePicker, MODIFIER_KEY      # installed via pip
import urwid                                                       # installed via pip

# Color schemes that specify the appearance off focus and on focus.
PALETTE = [("dp_barActive_focus",       "light gray",       ""),
           ("dp_barActive_offFocus",    "black",            ""),
           ("dp_barInactive_focus",     "dark gray",        ""),
           ("dp_barInactive_offFocus",  "black",            ""),
           ("dp_highlight_focus",       "black",            "brown",   "standout"),
           ("dp_highlight_offFocus",    "white",            "black")]

dp = DatePicker(month_names=[str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(13)],
                day_format=[DatePicker.DAY_FORMAT.DAY_OF_MONTH_TWO_DIGIT],
                columns=((6, DatePicker.PICKER.YEAR), (4, DatePicker.PICKER.MONTH), (4, DatePicker.PICKER.DAY)),
                min_width_each_picker=4,
                space_between=1,
                topBar_endCovered_prop=("ᐃ", "dp_barActive_focus", "dp_barActive_offFocus"),
                topBar_endExposed_prop=("───", "dp_barInactive_focus", "dp_barInactive_offFocus"),
                bottomBar_endCovered_prop=("ᐁ", "dp_barActive_focus", "dp_barActive_offFocus"),
                bottomBar_endExposed_prop=("───", "dp_barInactive_focus", "dp_barInactive_offFocus"),
                highlight_prop=("dp_highlight_focus", "dp_highlight_offFocus"))

pile = urwid.Pile([urwid.Text("press additionally the key modifier (default is 'ctrl')."),
                   urwid.Divider(" "),
                   dp])

loop = urwid.MainLoop(urwid.Filler(pile, "top"),
                      PALETTE)
loop.run()
```

[image: Demonstration of example 'ISO-8601 + Styled + Compact']

Comment: bravooo!! :clap: :clap: :clap! :)

Answer (score 1):

No, urwid doesn't have a datepicker, it's a complex widget to implement which deserves its own project, since these widgets usually need to take into consideration date format, locale, etc.

I don't know any urwid library that implements it and couldn't find any by scanning quickly the ones I know.

You can try to shop for a library, but you might have better luck implementing one yourself with your specific needs.

Comment: In the meantime I have written a rudimentary one (python3). For additional information see my answer.